# Big Query keeps on running queries; account deactived

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I've been trying out BigQuery for a week or so. I've linked BigQuery to one of our organizations Firebase projects. I used my free trial of Google Cloud Platform for this test. I didn't want to use BQ anymore, thus I deactived the link between Firebase and BQ. I also degraded our account from Blaze back to Spark. I assumed that, with the deactivation of the Blaze subscription and link between Firebase and BQ, no queries would be ran in BQ. This happened almost a week ago. However, this did not happen; the last query ran yesterday. I am not sure if I will be billed for these queries.

How do I cancel all queries in BQ in the future? I can't seem to find a(n easy) way to do that.

THanks in advance.

Comment: You can deactivate BigQuery from the Cloud Console for the project, right? With that said, it might be a good idea to figure out what is attempting to run the queries, too.

Comment: As Elliot has said, you need to figure out what/who is running those queries. Run `bq ls -j` and then examine the jobs using `bq show --format=prettyjson -j <job-id>` to see what's going on.